# What is the meaning of "others" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I came across a sentence on [a Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somatization_disorder), where "others" seems to have been used as a noun. Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary says it can either be noun or pronoun. The sentence in question is as follows:

> Somatization disorder also causes challenge and burden on the life of the caregivers or significant **others** of the patient.

What does "others" refer to in the statement above? Could it be a typo or does it refer to *relatives* and *close family members* of the *patient*?

Comment: My close limit for the day is reached. But this appears to be off-topic for insufficient research. Look up "*significant other*".

Comment: @drew i did not even in my dream think _significant_ was so important in role and should be googled with _others_ i thought it was grammar mistake

Comment: Possibly this is a candidate for the [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @NewAlexandria maybe it is. But it also deals with English language usage-not a basic one.

Comment: @MehdiHaghgoo I respect that you have learned much. I'm sure that I could not speak so much of your language. But you must understand that the word use, here, is basic to any fluent speaker – and is likely common to even most rough speakers.

Comment: @newalexandria you are right but I rarely learned ABC's of something formally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd like to highlight a slightly larger chunk in your sentence:

> Somatization disorder also causes challenge and burden on the life of the caregivers or **significant others** of the patient.

"Significant other" is a strong collocation; together, these words take on meaning beyond the two words separately. As explained on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_other):

> **Significant other** (abbreviated SO) is colloquially used as a gender-neutral term for a person's partner in an intimate relationship without disclosing or presuming anything about marital status, relationship status, or sexual orientation.

Without recognizing the full collocation, then "others" would indeed appear rather confusing.

Comment: +1, it would indeed be hard for me to get the tricky part without this accurate answer.

Comment: +1 This answer is surely going to be the only one for the question. Impossible to be original and come up with something better.

Comment: Surely, beyond a 'strong collocation': a compound noun.